# pt-online-schema-change: Unknown option: bin-log

Tags: mysql, percona, pt-online-schema-change

I am running the command `pt-online-schema-change --bin-log --host=127.0.0.1 --user=xxx --password=xxx D=xxx,t=xxx,P=8306 --alter "CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4" --execute`, however it outputs: "Unknown option: bin-log". There is a `--bin-log` option clearly mentioned in [their docs](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.0/pt-online-schema-change.html#cmdoption-pt-online-schema-change--bin-log), so what's going on? I have pt-online-schema-change 3.1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the documentation page, pt-online-schema-change does not have a `--bin-log` option. You can verify this by running:

```
pt-online-schema-change --help
```

I searched their bug database, and found that there is [some discussion](https://jira.percona.com/browse/PT-960) that it's important for pt-online-schema-change to write the binlog. It does this by default, and this matches my experience with it.

You don't need this option. I don't know why it appears in the documentation.